# Why evaluates "(Double.MinValue + 1) > Double.MinValue" to false?

Tags: .net, double

I first tried this (in vb.net)

```
(Double.MinValue + Double.Epsilon) > Double.MinValue
```

but that evaluates to false. Then I tried this

```
(Double.MinValue + 999999999999999999) > Double.MinValue
```

that evaluates to false, too.

Why?

Comment: Now I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.double.epsilon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx: "However, the Epsilon property is not a general measure of precision of the Double type; it applies only to Double instances that have a value of zero or an exponent of -1022."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adding a very small (magnitude) value to a very large (magnitude) makes: virtually no difference. In this case, the difference is so small that it **cannot be represented** within the precision of `double`. Basically:

```
double.MinValue + (most things) === double.MinValue
```

It doesn't guarantee to be able to represent every single `double` between `double.MinValue` and `double.MaxValue`, and as you increase the magnitude, the absolute resolution of what can be represented decreases.

Don't forget: `double.MinValue` has **308 digits** before the decimal place. You are altering very few of them. You are basically doing:

```
-179769313486232000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 // yikes!
+ 999999999999999999
```

Keep in mind that `double` has *roughly* 17 digits of precision; so about 291 digits of that huge number can be largely ignored.

Comment: double.MinValue * 0.999999999999 > double.MinValue should work if one wants a number that is not quite as negative as double.MinValue.

Comment: I think it should be `double.MinValue + most_things === most_things`

Comment: @MarcGravell my bad, I had thought that `double.MinValue` was the number with the smallest magnitude `(~1e-308)` I didn't realize it was a negative number with a large magnitude.